# Amazon EC2 becomes unresponsive when running two Mean pm2 processes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I have an amazon ec2 (t2.micro) instance running. I have 2 Mean applications hosted on it. It was working fine for more than 5 months. But from last two days when more than one `pm2` process starts the instance get stopped and I need to restart it again. With one `pm2` it is working fine but as I start the second `pm2` process it gets stopped (It becomes unresponsive and I can't login into) and again I need to reboot.

It was working fine with 3 to 4 `pm2` processes but from last 2 days it is not working as expected.I have checked the CloudWatch Logs but everything is fine there.

I am using Nginx server. I have checked nginx, pm2 and mongodb logs but nothing is wrong there.

Also, I have one Lightsail instance with 1GB memory and 40GB SSD. I have hosted 5 WordPress websites there. It is also having the same issues I need to reboot the instance more than twice a day.

I don't know what is the reason behind that so, asking here for help. Is there any issue with AWS EC2 or Lightsail instances?

This is EC2 CloudWatch graph please check.

[image]

Comment: You've checked CW Logs. What about CW Metrics? Maybe you are running at max CPU or RAM or disc (if you use CW Agent for these). Or metrics for status check, e.g. `StatusCheckFailed`.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the screenshot of the metrics, please check

Comment: Looks fine. Don't know. Can you got to `Health` service. Check if there are some notifications there. Maybe some temporary issues with the service itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "the instance get stopped and I need to restart it again"? Does the status of the instance in the EC2 console say `stopped`, or do you just mean that the instance becomes unresponsive and you can't login?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It becomes unresponsive and I can't login through any method

Comment: This would not be related to Amazon EC2. It would be due to the software configurations on the servers, and possibly running out of memory. You could experiment by increasing the instance size (which would give it more RAM), just to see whether this fixes the problem. You should also try debugging the situation by logging into the instance and then manually starting the processes, while monitoring system resources (eg with `top`). This will help identify if there is CPU or RAM exhaustion. Please note that t2.micro instances are burstable and you might be hitting CPU credit limits.